Excel VBA: named ranges aren't ranges at all? ByRef argument type mismatch
Consider this MWE:
Option Explicit
Sub test()
   Dim r1, r2 As Range
   Set r1 = Worksheets("MySheet").Range("MyNamedRange")
   Set r2 = NewRange(r1)
End Sub
Function NewRange(rng As Range) As Range
    Set NewRange = Offset(rng, 1, 1)
End Function

When I run test(), it says "ByRef argument type mismatch" and it highlights the r1 that is in the line
Set r2 = NewRange(r1)

What am I doing wrong?

That's because you did not declare r1 as a range. Dim r1, r2 As Range only declares r2as range, ´r1isVariant. You have to write Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range` How_to_Use_Dim_with_Multiple_Variables

Oh wow.... I've been doing that for a while now.  How has this just now become a problem????   Anyways tyvm

https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/#Passing_the_VBA_Array_to_a_Sub_or_Function Applies to Variant as well. Apart from that it's always best to declare a variable with its correct data type.

In VBA you can declare multiple variables in a single statement by separating each variable with a comma. However, there are some important details and potential pitfalls to be aware of.
Declaring Variables in a Single Statement
To declare multiple variables in one line, you simply list them with a comma between each, and specify their data types:
Dim var1 As Integer, var2 As String, var3 As Double
In this example:

var1 is declared as an Integer.
var2 is declared as a String.
var3 is declared as a Double.

If you don't explicitly declare the type of each variable, only the last variable will have the specified type, and the others will default to Variant, which can lead to unintended behavior.
Dim var1, var2, var3 As Integer  ' Only var3 is Integer; var1 and var2 are Variant

Correct way:
Dim var1 As Integer, var2 As Integer, var3 As Integer  ' All three are Integer

Default Data Type (Variant):
If you declare variables without specifying a type, they default to Variant, which can hold any type of data but is less efficient in terms of performance and memory usage.
Dim var1, var2, var3  ' All are Variant

Best Practice: Always specify the data type to avoid unintentional use of Variant.
Readability:
While declaring multiple variables in a single line can save space, it can also reduce the readability of your code, especially when the variables are of different types. It’s often clearer to declare each variable on a separate line, particularly in complex scripts.
Dim var1 As Integer
Dim var2 As String
Dim var3 As Double

Initialization:
When you declare multiple variables, none of them are initialized (assigned a value) automatically. They will hold default values (e.g., 0 for numeric types, empty string for String, Nothing for object types). If you need to initialize them, you must do so explicitly:
Dim var1 As Integer = 10, var2 As String = "Hello", var3 As Double = 5.5

Summary
Declare each variable's type explicitly to avoid unexpected Variant types.
Consider declaring variables on separate lines for better readability.
Remember that variables are not initialized automatically, so initialize them if needed.

You missed type definition for r1:
   Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

In this way
   Dim r1, r2 As Range

it's declared as Variant (by default):
   Dim r1 As Variant, r2 As Range


For convenience, set the "Require Variable Declaration" in "Tools/Options/Editor" and declare each variable with the required type. The Variant type is required in some cases only.

